# Python Dictreader Sorting Fieldnames

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I have a .csv file with the content (example)

```
Attributes,Description,Dial-Up
4,2,0.2
3,1,0.4
```

Using the dictreader:

```
dictreader = csv.DictReader(open(filename, "rb"), delimiter=',')
dictdata = {}
count=0
for row in dictreader:
    dictdata[count]=row
    count=count+1
```

And display in table or using writer i will get:

```
Dial-Up,Attributes,Description
0.2,4,2
0.4,3,1
```

So how can i sort the fieldnames?

Comment: please include the code which creates the display. its a crucial step in helping you. since that is actually what your question is about.

Comment: The `dict` type is unsorted. Why are you using `DictReader`? `csv.reader` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 10):

The `DictReader` stores the fields (dict keys) in an property called `fieldnames`:

```
fields = dictreader.fieldnames
print(fields)
# ['Attributes', 'Description', 'Dial-Up']
```

So to print the row values in this order:

```
print(','.join(fields))
for row in dictreader:
    print(','.join(row[field] for field in fields))
```

yields

```
Attributes,Description,Dial-Up
4,2,0.2
3,1,0.4
```

---

Or, using @JonClements' idea:

```
import operator
fields = dictreader.fieldnames
getfields = operator.itemgetter(*fields)
for row in dictreader:
    print(','.join(getfields(row)))
```

The motivation for using `operator.itemgetter` would be that it is faster than using a list comprehension:

```
In [70]: %timeit getfields(row)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 174 ns per loop

In [71]: %timeit [row[field] for field in fields]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 272 ns per loop
```

Comment: Alternatively - `print(','.join(itemgetter(*fields)))`

Comment: @JonClements: Your code for using `itemgetter` results in a `TypeError`.

Comment: @martineau Well, I admit to not testing it, but don't see why - and seems to work how unutbu has implemented it

Comment: @Jon Clements: What unutbu implemented in his updated answer is different in a significant way from the code you have in your comment. Apparently he was able to figure-out what you were trying to say.